# strpos not working with string containig forward salsh

Tags: php

I am trying to find weather string contain particular word by using php [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function and i have tried below code

```
echo strpos('sfsdf/abc/this', 'sfsdf/');
```

though it should return true because `sfsdf/` present in string  I am getting 0(false).

here is live example http://codepad.viper-7.com/dqvNCR

Comment: thanks, please write that as answer i will accept it. can i get end position of string as well as beginning ?

Comment: [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) returns the *position* of the found match. In this case it'll just be zero.

If you want a boolean result, then use `is_int(strpos(…))`.

Comment: Do you mean if your string where `abc/this/sfsdf/`? or `sfsdf/abc/this/sfsdf/`?

Comment: thanks i got that answer too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `0` you are getting is not false it is because the targeted value is the first value of your string.

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Demo:

```
echo strpos('asdf/sfsdf/abc/this', 'sfsdf/');
```

Output:

> 5

because the `sfsdf/` starts at the 6th position.

Live demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/NgQnxL

Answer (score 1):

Use `stristr` instead.

> Returns the matched substring. If needle is not found, returns FALSE.

```
<?php

if(stristr('sfsdf/abc/this', 'sfsdf/'))
{
    echo 1;
}
else
{
    echo 0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PkwTgo)

Comment: It worked like a charm,good work @Hassan

Comment: @AsimShahzad thank you.